# How can I set the value of an Angular formcontrol field from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, form-control

I have a "narrative" field in my formgroup. I have added the *Nanospell* Javascript spell checker to my project.

If there are misspelled words and I let the spell checker change them, the spell checker does its job and writes the corrected text string to `window.form1.narrative.value`. However, the underlying formcontrol value is still what is was previously with the misspelled words unless I physically type or backspace an additional character in that field after the spell checker is complete. Any user will not do that. They will click save when the spell checker is complete. The spell checker has an `onDialogComplete` Javascript function.

How can I use that Javascript function to set the updated value in the textbox to the formcontrol value so I am saving the correctly spelled text?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full Angular solution to make it all happen :-)

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { EditorFieldInfo } from '@app/shared/models/editorfieldinfo';

import 'tinymce';
declare let tinymce: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'rich-text-field',
  templateUrl: './rich-text-field.component.html'
})
export class RichTextFieldComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

  formControl: FormControl;

  editor: any;

  @Input()
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  @Input()
  fieldDefinition: EditorFieldInfo;

  constructor() { 
    this.fieldDefinition = { name: '??', description:'', placeholder:'', hint:'', fieldtype:'', length:0, defaultValue:'', listValues: null};      
  }

  ngOnInit(): void 
  {
    this.formControl = <FormControl> this.formGroup.get(this.fieldDefinition.name);         
  }
  
  ngAfterViewInit() { 

    let textAreaElement = 'mce-' + this.fieldDefinition.name;

    this.formControl.valueChanges.subscribe( _ => {
      tinymce.init({
        base_url: '/tinymce',
        suffix: '.min',
        selector: '#' + textAreaElement,
        toolbar: 'undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent',
        menubar: 'edit insert format table tools', branding: false, placeholder: '',
        external_plugins: {'placeholder': '/assets/scripts/placeholder.min.js'},
        content_style: 'body {font-weight: 400;line-height:1.125;font-family:RO Sans,Calibri,sans-serif;letter-spacing:normal;}',
        setup: editor => { 
          this.editor = editor; 
          editor.on('change', _ => this.formControl.setValue(editor.getContent()));                      
        }
      });  
    });

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);   
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to explicitly update the value of the `FormControl` in your `FormGroup` like this:

`this.{your_FormGroup_name}.get('{your_FormControl_name}').setValue('some_value');`

Comment: I put that exact line (modifying for my form group name, form control name, and the value I want to assign) in my javascript function and nothing happened. There is no script error in the console and my spell checker window stays open and does not respond. Obviously it cannot process that line of code.

Comment: Shortened Component HTML:<form id="timeentryform" [formGroup]="newTimeEntryForm" (ngSubmit)="addTimeEntry(newTimeEntryForm.value)" ><textarea formControlName="narrative" id="narrative" type="text" class="form-control" rows="4"></textarea></form> Javascript Function: function doSpellCheck() { var o = $Spelling.SpellCheckInWindow("narrative"); o.onDialogComplete = function() { this.newTimeEntryForm.get("narrative").value(window.timeentryform.narrative.value); } }

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally used the wrong function name, it should be `setValue`, edited. Seems like AJT_82 already answered earlier with the right documentation link as well.

Comment: Sorry, but this still does not work. I am doing this in straight JavaScript, not in TypeScript. The suggested fix appears to be a TypeScript line of code to put in my .ts file and that is not what I am doing. I need something to put in a Javascript block of code that is getting rendered to the DOM when my component loads. I need to update the formcontrol value via a JavaScript line of code.

Comment: Could you paste the component/file where you're trying to accomplish this?

Comment: I wound up doing this in my component file on my save function for my save button click and it works. Not really desirable but it works. this.narrative.setValue((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('narrative')).value);
    this.narrative.updateValueAndValidity();